# Модуль os, "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Последние дни питон выдает подобные ошибки:

```
import os

os.sys('echo 123')
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):     
>     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable  
>
>     os.sys('clean')
> ```

В чем дело и как исправить?

Comment: Не пытаться вызвать модуль `sys`, а использовать функцию `os.system`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно функцию [system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) использовать:

```
import os
os.system('echo 123')
```